# Looking for step by step guidance of deploying REST in IIS7

Tags: rest, deployment, iis-7

I'm looking for step by step guidance (for newbie) regarding how to deploy `REST` service (.NET 3.5 / Visual Studio 2008 SP1) in IIS 7

I would like deploy in localhost with no svc extension, so that I can access it using this format : http://localhost/restservice/employees.